# In Do Carmo's "Differential geometry of curves and surfaces" I don't understand how an angle in the section on Gauss Bonnet is measured

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

I am currently reading Do Carmo's chapter on the Gauss Bonnet theorem. On page 270, before stating the turning tangent theorem, he says:

> Let $\phi_i:[t_i,t_{i+1}]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be differentiable functions which measure at each $t \in [t_i,t_{i+1}]$ the positive angle from $\textbf{x}_u$ to $\alpha'(t)$

He then mentions to confer to Lemma 1 in Sec 4-4 on page 253, but I do not understand how we can use that lemma to prove those $\phi_i$ exist, since we don't know if $|\textbf{x}_u|=|\alpha'(t)|=1, t \in [t_i,t_{i+1}]$. Am I missing something?

Comment: Welcome. As it stands, someone who hasn’t a copy of the book doesn’t have enough information (I think) to answer. Please describe $x_u,\alpha$

Comment: $\alpha$ is a simple, closed, piecewise regular curve in a regular surface which has a conformal parametrization $\textbf{x}$ with coordinates (u,v). I can also link you a pdf of the book if that helps.

Comment: I would appreciate a link to the book on a personal level. For the sake of the rest of the post, you should edit in that extra detail to your main question

Comment: The book can be found here: http://www2.ing.unipi.it/griff/files/dC.pdf I referenced the book and didn't explicitly define everything because I think doing so would go beyond the scope of a post here.

Comment: I have a different edition of the book, so the numbers don't match up.  But I don't understand your point. The proof of the lemma/proposition you refer to starts by turning the two vector fields into unit vector fields.

Comment: That is true, the pages in question in this  version are 250 and 267. So I would turn the two vector fields $\textbf{x}_u$ and $\alpha'$ into unit vector fields and then apply the Lemma to measure the angle between the unit vectors?

Comment: Sure. No problem with that.